# I need Internal What mechnisum is happing Parent p= new Child()

Tags: java

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

When call using Parent method by using `p` reference the same method which is in Child class i.e.overriding. How Child method is executing instead of Parent class Method.

I need  What mechanism it is using internal

Comment: Here reference `p` is of `Parent` type Since You create an instance of `Child` class, all methods that are available in the child class will be visible to you.

Answer (score -1):

It is called Polymorphism and it is one of the 4 main aspect od Object Oriented Programming. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm